# How to read explorer folder address?

Tags: c++, c, directory, explorer, antivirus

I use AVG and it recently detected a virus. It has before ;) but this was the first time I noticed this.

When I went into the folder containing the virus, AVG immediately, automatically, detected the virus without me even clicking on the application. So I though how could it know a virus was there even when I did not even click (single click) on it.

The only possible answer is that it continuously checks the explorer folder location of all windows and scans all the files in the folder. But how does it see what folder is being viewed by me?

Please explain (if possible) with a C program that does what ever AVG did.

Also : I use Windows if that helps.

Comment: Virus checkers hook into the system calls that Windows uses to read files and folders. So when Windows detects that you are viewing a file or a folder the virus checker gets to run.

Comment: Could you please explain with code ?

Comment: The code how to hook into operating system? This is what viruses and worms and rootkits and virus checkers do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a folder a bunch of file system operations is executed (you can use tools like `FileMon` or `ProcMon` to take a look at this). Your AV software monitors file access.
There are multiple ways to do this monitoring, e.g. [Filter Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx) - you can find a great sample at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial

So when you opened the folder, AV software noticed that you opened a directory, consulted its own data, and informed you about the virus.

I say 'consulted its own data', as AV tools usually don't scan files on access - they do it  when the files are written to, as it doesn't make sense to scan files which were marked as clean if they haven't changed since the last scan.

Comment: Yes. it is located here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Most virus scanners operate on the principle of [API hooks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking)/filters.  Whenever windows needs to process a command, like opening a folder, clicking a window, executing a file, etc it generates an api call along with some information like the window coordinates clicked, or a string representing a file.  Other programs can request a hook into one or more of these functions which basically says 'instead of executing this function, send it to me first, then I might send it back'.  This is [how many viruses work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit) (preventing you from deleting them, or copying your keystrokes, for example), how many games/apps work (keyboard, joysticks, drag-and-drop), as well as malware detectors and firewalls.

The latter group hooks the commands, checks any incoming ones to see if they're on the level, then either allows them to resume or blocks them.  In this example, opening the folder likely triggered a syscall to parse a directory, and the scanner parsed it too (eg 'realtime protection').  To view all of your hookable functions as well as what is using them, google for a free program called '[sanity check](http://www.resplendence.com/sanity)' (previously called 'rootkit hook analyzer').  Most of the red entries will be from either windows firewall or avg, so don't worry too much about what you find.

Comment: So, just out of curiosity, will a AV detect another AV as a virus ?

Comment: No, because although it's hooked, they can still tell that it's a known AV.  Besides just looking at API hooks, an AV will also check running programs, libraries, services, system directory etc to see what else is running.